# Is it possible to pull metadata from JSON into a markdown file?

Tags: json, metadata, pug, markdown

I'm attempting to create a blog by using JSON with Jade and LESS, but I'm getting stuck in the fact that I cannot find a way to pull metadata from the JSON (like a date an article was published) into a markdown file. Is this even possible?

EDIT: Here is the JSON data I'm trying to pull:

> "initiate-colin": {
>
> "layout": "_layout",
>
> "title":"Initiate(Colin)",
>
> "date": "19 Jan 2014",
>
> "desc": "Meet and greet with me."
>
> }

I want the date to be displayed in a markdown file like this, but with #{ article.date } being replaced by "19 Jan 2014":

> ## Initiate Colin
>
> { article.date }

Comment: More information was added recently